# Speak directly to a PCI device without a driver?

Tags: pci, reverse-engineering

I have a friend who has a PCI device that has no driver. Is there a command that will allow me to speak to this device without a driver? (we are trying to reverse engineer its protocols.)

I will basically be fuzzing it with random data.

Answer (score 1):

The command [`setpci`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/setpci) might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score -1):

You can check if its getting detected by the OS. run the below command

#lspci  -----> check the output and see if you can get the attached PCI device

Comment: I don't want to find the device, I want to communicate with it. How might I do that?

Comment: Without the exact device Module, it will not communicate as you want.

Comment: Surely there is a way to pipe directly to an unknown device at a known location. This device has no driver